# Firewall Implementation

Tags: python, networking, ip-address, pox

I'm currently working with POX to create some firewall rules. First time going about the process and I'm a bit confused on something. If I want to block the addresses...

```
10.0.33.1
10.0.33.2
10.0.33.3
10.0.33.4
10.0.33.5
```

from sending info to a source ip address of 10.0.55.5, is there anyway I could group those ip addresses together instead of writing 5 different rules blocking them individually? I am incredibly new to this so any and all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't save much, but you can combine some of them into CIDR blocks:

```
10.0.33.1
10.0.33.2/31
10.0.33.4/31
```